# Is it possible to get better <code> support inside of posts?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

The Substrate StackExchange is primarily a developer community which involves lots of code, primarily Rust and JavaScript.

It seems the syntax highlighting on the Rust programming language is basically non-existent.

See this example from [this answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/194/what-extrinsics-filters-balances-to-block-transfers):

```
/// Use this filter to block users from calling any functions in the Balances pallet.
pub struct DontAllowBalances;
impl Contains<Call> for DontAllowBalances {
    fn contains(c: &Call) -> bool {
        // This will match against any call from the Balances pallet.
        !matches!(c, Call::Balances(..)
    }
}
```

Additionally, we do not seem to have support to write and execute simple JavaScript samples like StackOverflow has:

```
console.log("Hello, Stack Snippets!");
```

Can we enable these fuctionalities on this site?

Comment: It looks like syntax highlighting is not enabled on the site at all. It doesn't look like a rust specific issue. When inspecting the HTML elements, all code markdown is formatted with just `<pre><code></code></pre>` (no _highlight.js_ classes) regardless of if a language is specified or even when using the full `lang-` specifier notation.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be a bug. Posting code with ````rust` should highlight rust syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I've enabled syntax highlighting on Substrate's main site. Please refer to [Glorfindel's answer](https://substrate.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15/178) or this [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/208518) for some basic guidance on how to use it.

Comment: How can I associate the `[rust]` tag with `lang-rust`, so that users can put \`\`\`rust rather than ```lang-rust ?

Comment: Specifically, I don't see this feature: [When should the code language associated with a tag changed from "none" to "default"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130944/when-should-the-code-language-associated-with-a-tag-changed-from-none-to-defa)

Comment: That is a tool only moderators have access to. I've enabled it for the rust tag.

Comment: Thank's JNat that's much better!

Comment: So to be clear, rust snippets only are highlighted if they are tagged rust? This all code related questions must be tagged with this to get highlights? IMHO that is a be silly, as almost all questions will have this, and those without it very likely contain no snippets at all. The exception being JS primarily.

Comment: Can we also enable this for `javascript` / `js`? That should be the main two languages of this community.

Comment: @DanShields No that is not correct. You can tag code with `rust`, even if the `rust` tag is not present in that question.

Comment: also `json` and `typescript`/`ts` -- edit: json seems supported already :)

Answer (score 3):

ooh. If it could just default to ```rust if no other lang was specified that would be a ma zing.

Answer (score 3):

Syntax highlighting can be enabled by staff, but you have to tell the system which one (Rust, JavaScript, or something else) needs to be applied. That can be done in two ways:

- explicit specification with e.g. ```` ```lang-rust ````
- implicit specification via one of the question's tags – these need to be specified by moderators or staff. For an example, see the bottom of the [rust tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) on Stack Overflow

I'm not sure if it's possible to set a default syntax highlighting; code blocks can also be used for other purposes (e.g. console output) for which syntax highlighting would be confusing.

Comment: Well if any staff sees this, I would love to have syntax highlighting enabled on this site. I expect there will be a lot of code.

Comment: +1 I would really love the syntax highlighting, ideally on par with github using `rust` and other keywords, ideally not `lang-rust` if possible for brevity. Already there are snippets of *many* languages, so I would opt for more is better now over trying to cherry pick specific langs.

Comment: I see ```rust seems to work. Nice!

Comment: @Squirrel that's because staff (apparently) associated the [tag:rust] tag with the `rust` language.